# How to map multiple Internal Resources in Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

In my project there is SpringMVC InternalResourceViewResolver used for root URL mapping to redirect to home page.

Without affecting the existing application I need to add a Internal Resource view resolver so that I can move some pages inside WEB-INF and protect direct access.

So far I have found that Spring MVC allows only one InternalResourceViewResolver and adding **order** element is not working as well.

Here is the spring xml for reference which is not working.
I need to add the second resolver so direct access to pages can be prevented, these pages are currently outside WEB-INF and I am looking for a working SpringMVC configuration so that I can move these:

```
<bean id="firstViewResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.ftl</value>
    </property> <property name="order" value="0"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="secondViewResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.ftl</value>
    </property> <property name="order" value="1"/> 
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**
Since none of the approaches seems to work for me, i am trying Servlet filter or listener approach to perform this task. Spring MVC should have a permanent solution for this as it seems a common requirement and I see many people struggling for this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring wont allow you to define 2 internalResourceViewResolvers. now you have two options:

- you can move all the files with .ftl extension into your pages folder inside 
  WEB-INF and go ahead with your "secondViewResolver".
- You can go ahead with "firstViewResolver" and access the view inside pages 
  folder by returning string like

  "WEB-INF/pages/YourViewName.ftl"

  from your controller while you access the views outside of WEB-INF/pages 
  directory by 
  returning string like

  "YourViewName.ftl".
- You can go ahead with "secondViewResolver" and access the view outside of 
  WEB-INF/pages by returning string like

  "../../YourViewName.ftl"

  from your 
  controller while you access views inside pages folder by returning string 
  like

  "YourViewName.ftl".
- another solution would be to include different viewResolvers. eg: you can add 
  a urlBasedViewResolver and a internalResourceViewResolver each with different 
  prefix and orders.

Comment: How can i go with secondViewResolver if i cant have 2 view resolver of same type? Also I dont want to change existing logic (first view resolver). Is there any other view resolver that can be used here(other than InternalResourceViewResolver)?

Comment: what i ment was you can either use prefix as "/WEB-INF/pages/" like you have done in your bean with id "secondViewResolver".

Comment: if you dont want to change anything in your logic, then your best bet is to either have all your .ftl files inside WEB-INF/pages or have all your .ftl files  outside of it.

Comment: i have edited my answer. the 4th point should help you. please try using urlBasedViewResolver along with internalResourceViewResolver

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your files to a new folder called freemaker inside resources folder along with this config:

```
<mvc:view-resolvers>
    <mvc:content-negotiation>
        <mvc:default-views>
            <bean id="firstViewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
                <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/</value>
                </property>
                <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.ftl</value>
                </property> <property name="order" value="0"/> 
            </bean>
        </mvc:default-views>
    </mvc:content-negotiation>
    <mvc:freemarker cache="false"/>
</mvc:view-resolvers>

<mvc:freemarker-configurer>
    <mvc:template-loader-path location="/freemarker"/>
</mvc:freemarker-configurer>
```

[From the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-view-resolvers)

*Note however that **FreeMarker**, Velocity, Tiles, Groovy Markup and script templates also require configuration of the underlying view technology.
The MVC namespace provides dedicated elements. **For example with FreeMarker:***

```
<mvc:view-resolvers>
    <mvc:content-negotiation>
        <mvc:default-views>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
        </mvc:default-views>
    </mvc:content-negotiation>
    <mvc:freemarker cache="false"/>
</mvc:view-resolvers>

<mvc:freemarker-configurer>
    <mvc:template-loader-path location="/freemarker"/>
</mvc:freemarker-configurer>
```